# carousell every div does something else onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just need some advice and help. I have 7 different divs and every div should do something else when clicking on it (owl carrousel).

Now i just have everything "hard coded" but that is not very efficiënt

Example:

when i click div 1:   $(".div1").css('-webkit-filter','blur(5px)');

when i click div 2:   $(".div2").css('-webkit-filter','grayscale(100%');

etc.

Do i need to keep "hard coded" or is there a better solution for my question?.

I am a real newbie.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can define an array of actions and assign the action to an element based on its position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like:

```
/* Array of effects */
var effectArray = ['blur(5px)', 'grayscale("100%")'];

$(".divClass").click(function () {
    // Wrap the clicked item in jQuery.
    // .index() get its index 0 to "n".
    $(this).css('-webkit-filter', effectArray[$(this).index()]);
});
```

EDIT i forgot to wrap the divclass in jQuery. you can obviously do this without jQuery too

Also just realized you want it on click.

Comment: You could also do this on pressing your mouse button, and then undoing the effect when you release. (or hover).

Comment: thx mr puzzle! you really helpt me out! but do i just loop through the array now or what do i do?

Comment: give all your divs the same class. and add equal amount of effects to the effectArray. then it'll work like that.

Comment: ye thx i just looked the documentation up for .index() again thanks

Comment: the weird thing is its only doing the blur effect and not the grayscale effect? even when i click on second div it shows blur effect

Comment: did give all your divs the same class? and are they in the same parent container?

Comment: <div id="container">
 <div id="filterslider">
    
        <div class="overlay"></div>
     <div class="overlay"></div>
  


 </div>
</div>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sLsfe6pw/1/ remove the quotes for the 100% in greyscale. also try to make a js fiddle with your code so we can debug.

Comment: or do you want to apply an effect on another div depending on which div you click? in that case: https://jsfiddle.net/sLsfe6pw/2/